# Sql Query to join two tables get data with following result

Tags: sql-server, database

Heloo,

i have 2 Tables Table 1 and Table 2 having many to many relation, both table have foreign keys RecID.

```
Table
 ID  Amount  RecID
 1   100     10
 2   300     4
 3   400     5
 4   500     5

Table 2
ID Amount RecID
1  50     10
2  50     10
3  300    4
4  900    5
```

i need to join both tables to get all rows from both tables like this.

```
Result Table
AmountTable 1   RecIDTable1  AmountTable2  RecIDTable2
100             10           50            10 
Null            Null         50            10
300             4            300           4
400             5            900           5
500             5            Null          Null
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, and, hence, needs some complex SQL to achieve. - Anyway, you have to specify which records you want to join and which records not to join. For us, and later in your query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  And realize that is an instance where your DB tag will dramatically determine the answer to your question.

Comment: i am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I posted this answer at a point when the OP had specified both MySQL and SQL Server as tags.

You are trying to do a full outer join of the two tables.  Since there is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL, you have to achieve it some other way.  One way is to do a `UNION` of a left and right join between the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.Amount AS AmountTable1, t1.RecID AS RecIDTable1,
    t2.Amount AS AmountTable2, t2.RecID AS RecIDTable2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.RecID = t2.RecID
UNION
SELECT t1.Amount AS AmountTable1, t1.RecID AS RecIDTable1,
    t2.Amount AS AmountTable2, t2.RecID AS RecIDTable2
FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.RecID = t2.RecID
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1036/2)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned the SQL-Server tag in your question. So here is the query using  `Full Outer Join` like this -

```
SELECT
    t1.Amount AS AmountTable1
    ,t1.RecID AS RecIDTable1
    ,t2.Amount AS AmountTable2
    ,t2.RecID AS RecIDTable2
FROM @tab1 t1
FULL JOIN @tab2 t2
    ON t1.RecID = t2.RecID
```